# Get current logged in user flutter/mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flutter, http

Hello I was wondering how can I get the current logged in user in flutter with mongoDB, I save the token in sharedpreferences and the user logs in if the token was valid, but I have two problems the first one is not knowing how to get only the current user's username as well as how to give the user privileges only on the posts he adds

**Here's my post module **
`

```
class Post {
  // final User? user;
  final String id;
  final User author;
  final String text;
  final List<dynamic>? images;
  final List<dynamic>? videos;
  final List<dynamic> likes;
  final List<dynamic> comments;
  final String date;

  Post(
      {required this.id,
   
      required this.author,
      required this.date,
      // required this.author,
      required this.likes,
      required this.comments,
      required this.category,
      this.images,
      this.videos,
      required this.text
      // this.userId,
      });

 

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Post(
      id: map['_id'],
      date: map['createDate'],
      likes: map['likes'] ?? [0],
      comments: map['comments'] ?? [0],
      // user: map[''],
      author: User.fromJson(map['author']),
      // author: map[''],
      images: map['images'] ?? [''],
      videos: map['videos'] ?? [''],
      text: map['text'],
      // author: map['author'],
    );
  }
```

`

**Here's my user module**

`

```
class User {
  final String? id;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String token;
  final String profileImage =
      'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1393750072/vector/flat-white-icon-man-for-web-design-silhouette-flat-illustration-vector-illustration-stock.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=s9hO4SpyvrDIfELozPpiB_WtzQV9KhoMUP9R9gVohoU=';

  User({
    // required this.profileImage,
    required this.username,
    this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.token,
  });

 

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return User(
      // profileImage: map[''].toString(),
      id: map['_id'].toString(),
      username: map['username'].toString(),
      email: map['email'].toString(),
      password: map['password'].toString(),
      token: map['token'].toString(),
    );
  }
```

`

I tried to many things but I'm new to flutter and not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

So Auth0 has a pretty awesome official package. If you use this you can request basic data like this:

```
final userProfile = await auth0.api.userInfo(accessToken: accessToken);
```

This will give you give the user credentials you need.

if you do not use this package please do, it is simple and easy to use.

Here is a link to the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/auth0_flutter

Here is a link to the documentation: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-flutter/blob/main/auth0_flutter/EXAMPLES.md#retrieve-user-information

Comment: I'm really new to coding, you think you can help me more with this? I'd really appreciate it if you can help me on step by step!